# Display row of another table as column of current table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Consider there are two tables:
Table1:

```
**Result          Total**
Pass             102
Fail              3
Undetermined      1
```

Table 2:

```
**Pass%   Fail%   Undetermined%**   
  96.23   2.83    0.94
```

Result Needed:

```
**Result     Total  Percentage**
Pass          102       96.23
Fail           3        2.83
Undetermined   1        0.94
```

How to convert the table 2 rows as column in table 1 to obtain the result ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us that you put some effort into solving this issue instead of asking for us to do it for you?

Comment: I am not experienced in mssql am in my learning phase. I did enough research and couldn't sort out that is the reason I have posted here. If you don't want to answer I don't expect from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, You can try to do `unpivot` on `Table2`, then `JOIN` with `Table1`.

Your `sql-server` version is 2008, you can use `unpivot` by `UNION ALL`.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  Result  VARCHAR(50),
  Total int
);
CREATE TABLE T2(
  Pass  FLOAT,
  Fail FLOAT,
  Undetermined FLOAT
);

insert into T2 VALUES (96.23,2.83,0.94)



INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Pass',102);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Fail',3);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Undetermined',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.*,s.val
FROM ( 
  SELECT Pass val,'PASS' Name
  FROM T2 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Fail val,'Fail' Name
  FROM T2 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Undetermined val,'Undetermined' Name
  FROM T2 
) s inner join T1 t1 on t1.Result = s.Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1087c/3/0)**:

```
|       Result | Total |   val |
|--------------|-------|-------|
|         Pass |   102 | 96.23 |
|         Fail |     3 |  2.83 |
| Undetermined |     1 |  0.94 |
```

---

If you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUE` you can try this.

**Query**:

```
SELECT t1.*,s.val
FROM (
  SELECT v.* FROM T2 
  CROSS APPLY(VALUES 
       (Pass,'PASS'),
       (Fail,'Fail'),
       (Undetermined,'Undetermined')
  ) v(val,Name)
) s inner join T1 t1 on t1.Result = s.Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1087c/3/0)**:

```
|       Result | Total |   val |
|--------------|-------|-------|
|         Pass |   102 | 96.23 |
|         Fail |     3 |  2.83 |
| Undetermined |     1 |  0.94 |
```

Comment: Thanks much :) I tried Pivot on table 2, but failed in joining the tables.

Comment: Sure, Thank you :)

Comment: I am not able to vote, showing some msg that i will not be able to record vote :(